# show pins around 100kilometers

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

i am implementing an app, that show customers and my userLocation on a map.
But now i have a problem, because there are a lot of costumers and the map is very uncomfortable.

How can i only see pins on a map or in a list, that are around 100 kilometers away from 
me?

I hope someone could help me?

Greetings Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should cache your current location in a CLLocation* variable.
You have to calculate the distance of every pin (annotation) you add from this location using [myLoc getDistanceFrom:pinLoc] which returns a CLLocationDistance i believe. If this is > 100 kms don't add it to your map.